# Instagram basic display api app review rejected, i need to get reel data like author, caption, timestamp

Tags: node.js, facebook, web-scraping, instagram

[image]I am using instagram basic display api for getting data about reel like caption, author, timestamp, since Instagram doesn't allow web scraping so i tried to use the api and i got a long-live access token but when i try to get data the response is "Unsupported request, missing permission", So I submit app for review and said that i need the permission to get reel data like i said above and the app review rejected from them as shown in the photo below, any tips ?

I need to get any reel data like author, caption, timestamp